# Second Dynamic DIV over writes first dynamic DIV

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamically-generated

I have searched for almost three days now and I can't find an answer to this question. As I am somewhat new to ASP.Net I am not sure what the problem is.
Here is the situation. I have an aspx page that has a web form on it. When this form loads it has two SQL queries that execute and populate different controls.

My problem lies not with the queries but creating dynamic DIV tags and adding controls to them. If the query returns one or no records everything is fine. but if there are 2 or more records returned I only end up with the last record being displayed.

When I view the page source (from the browser) I can see the DIV tag ID that was created last, but the first DIV tag is gone. It is like the first DIV tag gets over written or something. I have no idea as to why or what is causing this.

Can anyone help please?

Here is my code:

```
    While (incCounter <= rowCount)
        DivName.ID = ("rev" & Convert.ToString(incCounter)) 'Create Div name of rev and the current counter number ex. rev1
        review_comments.Controls.Add(DivName) 'Add DIV to web form
        rName = (rName & Convert.ToString(incCounter)) 'Create name control name
        rDate = (rDate & Convert.ToString(incCounter)) 'Create date control name
        rComments = (rComments & Convert.ToString(incCounter)) 'Create comment control name
        DivName.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        DivName.Controls.Add(rRevByLabel)
        rNameTextBox.ID = rName
        DivName.Controls.Add(rNameTextBox)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(nbSpace)
        DivName.Controls.Add(rDateLabel)
        DivName.Controls.Add(rDateTextBox)
        DivName.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
        DivName.Controls.Add(rCommentLabel)
        DivName.Controls.Add(rCommentsTextBox)
        'Assign data from query to new textboxes
        rNameTextBox.Text = dtR.Rows(incCounter - 1)("reviewed_by_name").ToString()
        rDateTextBox.Text = dtR.Rows(incCounter - 1)("reviewed_by_date").Date()
        rCommentsTextBox.Text = dtR.Rows(incCounter - 1)("review_comments").ToString()

        rName = "revName"
        rDate = "rDate"
        rComments = "revComments"
        incCounter += 1
    End While
```

I know all the variables are set up correctly because it shows me the last record.

What stupid thing am I doing?

Comment: create the new div inside the while and add it to review_comments. You are just replacing the id as far as i can tell. and i presume all controls are getting added to one div and the div id changed to last iteration id.

Comment: No this line should be creating the DIV:

Comment: review_comments.Controls.Add(DivName) 'Add DIV to web form

Comment: Here is the SQL command

        'SQl Query Setup Information
        Dim dtR As New DataTable()
        Dim connStringR As String = "Data Source=O-SN-2I-LT-101\SQLEXP14;Initial Catalog=PAR;User ID=***;Password=*************"
        Dim connectionR As New SqlConnection(connStringR)
        Dim sqlCmdR As New SqlCommand("Select par_num, reviewed_by_name, reviewed_by_date, review_comments From tbl_Reviewed_By Where par_num = @parnumber")
        Dim sqlDaR As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmdR)
        connectionR.Open()
        sqlCmdR.Connection = connectionR

Comment: sqlCmdR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parnumber", sendingStringR)
        sqlDaR.Fill(dtR)

        rowCount = dtR.Rows.Count

Remove ID and PW of course